# Are discussions concerning emulation/emulating off topic?

Tags: discussion

I've often seen some questions be buried because the question asked about things that were concerning emulators or emulation in general.

But this one seems to be going fine: [How to set BIOS file in go PSX emulator free?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303491/how-to-set-bios-file-in-go-psx-emulator-free)

So is there an official guideline about questions on emulation or is it more just the community goes that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulation is a bit of tricky topic because its relation to piracy. Which isn't to say all emulation questions are off-topic or that everyone who uses an emulator is pirating. One rule that I know of for sure is that questions about ROMs/ISOs and how to get them are double no-good. To extrapolate from this, try to avoid questions about games and instead ask questions pertinent to the emulation software itself.